# What is it called to check your co-ordinates on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is it called to check your co-ordinates on Minecraft? I need to change it on my laptop since the F1, F2 , etc... are being used

Comment: What do you mean by "are being used"? I know laptop keyboards are usually compressed and so require you to press/toggle the Function key to get certain keypresses like the F-numbers...

Comment: If you have something like a MacBook and you mean that F3 is assigned to something like system volume or brightness, use FN+F3 to use it for the debug screen.

Answer (score 2):

As @Trent Hawkins said, try using the  Fn key and F3. There is, however no (vanilla) way to rebind the debug key.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the 'debug' screen, however, there is no way to change the keybinding from <kbd>F3</kbd> by default in vanilla Minecraft.